# Check what event called the trigger on PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, trigger, plpgsql

I'm trying to check what event called my trigger, like `INSERT`, `UPDATE` or `DELETE`.

Oracle triggers can check this in a simple 'IF' statement:

```
IF INSERTING, IF UPDATING or even IF DELETING
```

Is there a similar statement on PostgreSQL?

Usually I just create a function for `INSERT`, an other one for `UPDATE` and one more for `DELETE`, but it's a waste of code if there's some way to create just one function.

Can someone help?

Comment: "*Can someone help?*" - the manual contains this information.

Comment: I don't think it's waste of code.  Generally and even more in the case of complex trigger behaviour I feel safer to keep my triggers and corresponding procedures separated from each other.  It makes debugging cleaner, for example.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Trigger functions can check the value of the `TG_OP` variable to determine the event which caused the trigger to fire.  There are a number of other special variables as well [listed in the documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/plpgsql-trigger.html).